# Cant get access to service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the second problem: cloud sql proxy pod wrapped onto service and must provide access to database.

And I have a job which must create new database for every branch.

But when this job runs the second error appears. I cant get access to the cloudsql-proxy-service.

I cant understand why its happens. Thanks.

> E  psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
>
> E     Is the server running on host "cloudsql-proxy-service"
>   (10.43.254.123) and accepting
>
> E     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: cloudsql-proxy
    labels:
        type: backend
        name: app
    annotations:
        "helm.sh/created": {{ .Release.Time.Seconds | quote }}
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-20"
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            name: cloudsql-proxy
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                name: cloudsql-proxy
        spec:
            containers:
            -   name: cloudsql-proxy
                image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
                command:
                - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
                - "-instances={{ .Values.testDatabaseInstanceConnectionName }}=tcp:5432"
                - "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"
                securityContext:
                    runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
                    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
                volumeMounts:
                -   name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
                    mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
                    readOnly: true
                ports:
                  - containerPort: 5432
            volumes:
            -   name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
                secret:
                    secretName: {{ .Values.cloudSqlProxySecretName }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cloudsql-proxy-service
  labels:
    type: backend
    name: app
  annotations:
      "helm.sh/created": {{ .Release.Time.Seconds | quote }}
      "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
      "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-20"
spec:
  selector:
      name: cloudsql-proxy
  ports:
      - port: 5432


apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
    name: create-test-database
    labels:
        type: backend
        name: app
    annotations:
        "helm.sh/created": {{ .Release.Time.Seconds | quote }}
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-10"
spec:
    template:
        metadata:
          name: create-test-database
        spec:
            containers:
            -   name: postgres-client
                image: kalumkalac/postgresql-client
                env:
                    -   name: PGUSER
                        value: {{ .Values.testDatabaseCredentials.username }}
                    -   name: PGPASSWORD
                        value: {{ .Values.testDatabaseCredentials.password }}
                    -   name: PGDATABASE
                        value: {{ .Values.testDatabaseCredentials.defaultDatabaseName }}
                    -   name: PGHOST
                        value: cloudsql-proxy-service
                command:
                    - psql
                    - -q
                    - -c CREATE DATABASE {{ .Values.testDatabaseCredentials.name|quote }}
            restartPolicy: Never
    backoffLimit: 0 # Deny retry job
```

Comment: I will suggest 1st, try restarting the CloudSQL instance.
Second, I recommend checking [Google’s CloudSQL proxy tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine) for connecting with GKE. Ensure you haven’t missed any minor details that may be causing the error. At the moment I suspect there is some misconfiguration/mismatch in port’s or hostnames.

Comment: Lastly, please try running 

`gcloud sql instances describe [SQL_INSTANCE_NAME]`

See that the name provided matches the live deployment file where “{{ .Values.testDatabaseInstanceConnectionName }}” exists. Also, if you could provide the live deployment's yaml with command below, it would help greatly. Please redact any personal information. 

`kubectl get pod <running pods name> -o yaml`

Comment: Are you sure that your cloud-sql-proxy deployment is functioning?
run kubectl describe deployment  cloudsql-proxy and post the output. 
Many times there is an issue that the secret does not exist and the proxy is failing to launch. Did you created the secret? Make sure that  .Values.cloudSqlProxySecretName is indeed credentials.json as you pointed in "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json". I guess you should change the command to take the value from the helm values as well